# How could i push the values to instead nan in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I set a dataframe using the following code：

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','c'],'B':[123,456,555,888]})
```

I then execute the following code：

```
pd.pivot(df.A, df.index, df.B)
```

The dataframe changes to this:

[image: pic1]

Now I want to know how to move non-NAN values to the front columns like this:

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pivot`ing (and then repairing the result), you could use `groupby`:

```
In [321]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','c'],'B':[123,456,555,888]})

In [322]: df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack()
Out[322]: 
       0      1
A              
a  123.0  456.0
b  555.0    NaN
c  888.0    NaN
```

---

Or, alternatively, use `groupby/cumcount` to assign the correct column numbers per group,
and then `pivot`:

```
In [325]: df.assign(C=df.groupby('A').cumcount()).pivot(index='A', columns='C', values='B')
Out[325]: 
C      0      1
A              
a  123.0  456.0
b  555.0    NaN
c  888.0    NaN
```

Comment: @ltdong7788 seems like your question and your excepted not match

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x : x[x.notnull()].values.tolist(),1).apply(pd.Series)
Out[262]: 
       0      1
A              
a  123.0  456.0
b  555.0    NaN
c  888.0    NaN
```

Comment: Your answer is also perfect.But sorry for i didn't express my question well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain same amount of columns with `NaNs`

```
In [585]: dff = pd.pivot(df.A, df.index, df.B)

In [586]: (dff.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
              .reindex_axis(dff.columns, 1))
Out[586]:
       0      1   2   3
A
a  123.0  456.0 NaN NaN
b  555.0    NaN NaN NaN
c  888.0    NaN NaN NaN
```

If you don't need to

```
In [587]: dff.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
Out[587]:
       0      1
A
a  123.0  456.0
b  555.0    NaN
c  888.0    NaN
```